# How to Package a JavaFX Application as a standalone executable EXE using Gradle

Tags: gradle, javafx

I recently downloaded the `JavaFX 12 SDK` and started a `Gradle Application` in IntelliJ IDE.I have also imported all the necessary dependencies in the `build.gradle` file. Now I want to package the final `JavaFX application` as a standalone executable exe file that can be clicked and run on Windows. How can I do this since I started the project as a Gradle Project. The `Build Artifact` Menu Item on IntelliJ seems to be permanently disabled.

Here is a setup of my `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

javafx {
    version = "12.0.1"
    modules = ['javafx.base', 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.web']
}

group 'condo'
version '1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = 'rumbler.launcher.ApplicationLoader'

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation group: 'org.iq80.leveldb', name: 'leveldb', version: '0.12'
    implementation 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
}
```

Thanks alot.